# No data written in Mongo database after Process.Exit()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm writing a node.js script to write in a MongoDB database some data from a MySQL database. It is not a web application, but a local script (both my MySQL and Mongo are local).

The problem is that when all data is written, the script doesn't terminate. I have to close it with CTRL+C. But all my data is written in my MongoDB database.

I've added a "process.exit()" line at the end of the callback called after writing in MongoDB. The app terminates, but no data is written ! And I don't understand why.

Here is the relevant portion of code

```
(...)
var req = "SELECT * FROM geometry";

// "connection" is a MySQL connection
connection.query(req, function(err, rows, fields) {
    console.log("number of lines :" + rows.length);
    connection.end();

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    // "Entry" is my model
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        Entry.create({
            "code" : rows[i].code,
            "name" : rows[i].name,
            "coords" : rows[i].coords,
            "type" : rows[i].type
        }, function(err, doc){
            if (err) {
                throw (err);
            }
        });
    }

    console.log("end");
    process.exit(); // no data written ! why ?
});
```

Can you help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you're not used to thinking asynchronously. Try reading this question and answer and see if you understand how you're doing the same mistake in your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your link switched on a light in my brain :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're terminating you process too early. You're not waiting for `mongoose` to actually send any of your documents to MongoDB. Here are some examples of how to do it properly.

**N.B.** Please, first [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) to understand *why no data is written*, then read my answer to know *how to deal with it*.

---

### Using promises and [when.js](https://github.com/cujojs/when) module

First we should require `when` module (or any other promise-based control flow module, e.g. [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)).

```js
when = require('when');
```

then we could use it to simplify our code:

```
promises = rows.map(function(row) {
  return Entry.create(row);
})
when.all(promises).otherwise(console.error).ensure(function() {
  process.exit()
})
```

or using `when.map`:

```
when.map(rows, function(row) {
  return Entry.create(row);
}).otherwise(console.error).ensure(function() {
  process.exit()
})
```

**N.B.** This solution is possible dye to mongoose [build-in promises support](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create).

---

### Using [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) module

`async.js` is a callback-based control flow module for node.js:

```
async = require('async');
```

but it is almost as powerful as promises are:

```
async.map(roes, function(row, next) {
  Entry.create(row, next);
}, function(err){
  if (err) throw (err);
  process.exit();
});
```

---

### Using pure JavaScript

But we can achieve the same results using pure callbacks-based JavaScript:

```
var pending = 0;
rows.forEach(function(row) {
  pending++;
  Entry.create(row, function(err) {
    if (err) throw (err);
    if (--pending === 0) process.exit();
  });
});
```

---

### *Note on `mongoose`*

Bu default mongoose uses [strict mode](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict), so I simply call

```
Entry.create(row);
```

knowing that mongoose will strip any property of `row` which is not in present in `Entry` schema.

---

### *Note on asynchronous code and control flow modules*

Control flow modules (promises, async.js, etc) helps you deal with asynchronous code, but if you're new to node.js and asynchronous programming I would recommend you to start from pure JS approach in order to understand node.js better. Then it'll be safe to adopt some control flow solution.

You should also note that promises provide a huge abstraction layer for your asynchronous code with a lot of syntactic sugar, while callbacks-based modules like async.js provide just a little bit of it.

So, in my opinion the best way to master node.js is the following:

```
Pure JS -> callback-based modules (async.js) -> promises
```

Latest node.js 0.11.x (with `--harmony` flag) also support [generators](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/how-to-generators-node-js-yield-use-cases/), providing yet another way to deal with asynchronous code.

Comment: Ok, I got it. So I will try the pure JS approach. I suppose I will have to keep track of the number of created users, and send a process.exit() in Create() callback as soon as this number is equal to my MySQL dataset number of rows ?